# Magento 2: Expand/Collapse sidebar menu

Tags: jquery, magento, magento2

I am trying to run following script to add expand/collapse in magento 2 however when event is clicked in frontend the error generates.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $header is not defined
```

Code i am using is

```
define([
"jquery"
], function($){
"use strict";
return function sidebar(config, element) {
 
    $(".filter-ab").click(function () {

        $header = $(this);
        //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();
        //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
            //execute this after slideToggle is done
            //change text of header based on visibility of content div
            $header.text(function () {
                //change text based on condition
                return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
            });
        });

    });

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use var header instead of $header